# EXPO react-native-svg Error:- "Error while updating property 'd' of a view managed by: RNSVGPath null . For input string: "c"

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-svg, react-native-svg-charts

There seems to be an issue with the react-native-svg and android. This error is being thrown in my *Android* app only - the iOS app seems to be fine? The error message gives me no indication as to where the error may be occurring. Any ideas would be helpful...

CODE:

```
import { Circle } from 'react-native-svg';

    <Circle
       cx="0"
       cy="0"
       r={size / 2 - 6}
       fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)" // Transparency
     />
```

---

`"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-native-svg": "9.5.3",
"react-native-svg-charts": "^5.3.0",`

[image]

UPDATE:

I *think* have found the root of the error. Within `node_modules>react-native-svg>elements>Path.js>Path>render` there is a requirement for a props 'd' - it reads:

```
<RNSVGPath
 ref={this.refMethod}
 {...extractProps(propsAndStyles(props), this)}
 d={props.d}
/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I removed the version in my project using
yarn remove react-native-svg
then I ran
yarn add react-native-svg@9.13

***that solved my issue

Comment: I have the same issue and downgrading from react-native-svg@12.1.0 to 9.13 solved it for me as well

Comment: weird, downgrading a solution?

Comment: Yes, downgrading it solved the issue.